# how to validate special characters from utf8 character set in zend php

Tags: zend-framework, utf-8, validation

I am using multilingual characters, use utf8 encoding. Now i need to validate it and avoid special characters while entering it.Is there any way to identify special characters while using multilingual character inputs? what i mean is we can validate special chars like !@%%^&.. while using english.I am looking for the same type of validation.

anybody please help me...

I am using zend php.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one "!", "@", "%", "^" and "&" character respectively. There's not an "English !" and a "Spanish !" and an "Indian !" and a "Korean !". They're all the same character. If they're encoded in UTF-8, they're even the same byte as ASCII encoded characters. You can look for them and replace them as before.

There may be characters that *look similar*, like "！" (fullwidth exclamation mark), but that's not the same character as "!" and hence does not have a special meaning if "!" has a special meaning.

Comment: ok.. thank you.. what i thought was, some other language may use special character as it's character set

Comment: hai,Now, I want to validate characters basis of language that select previously. any way of doing it??? Means, if i am selecting hindi , then i want to restrict other languages like spanish or..other languages entering from users

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Zend_Validate_Alnum`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.alnum) validator, it's unicode ready.

Comment: hai,Now, I want to validate characters basis of language that select previously. any way of doing it??? Means, if i am selecting hindi , then i want to restrict other languages like spanish or..other languages entering from users.